# Is it a bad practice for a class to import classes in its subpackages in Java?

Tags: java, package

I heard that there are some principles when importing other classes in Java. One of them is that it is a bad practice for a class to import classes in its subpackages as follows:

```
package com.example.java.packg;

import com.example.java.packg.a.A;
import com.example.java.packg.a.B;
...
```

Is it real?

Answer (score -2):

Well, you'd have to ask whomever is peddling the thought that this is bad practice.

But I can take a stab at it:

## Reference loops

If the code in file `A.java` cannot be compiled without the presence of `B.java` (because, for example, A has `import B;` in it), and `B.java` cannot be compiled without the presence of `A.java` (for example, because B is defined as `public class B extends A` - which more or less matches your example here), then that's a little bit annoying.

It is now impossible to compile these 2 files unless you compile them together, which java can do for you, at least. But it also means attempting to understand what `A` does requires that you nkow what B does, but do know what B does, you have to understand what A does: They are now intertwined; you cannot compile them separately, and you cannot understand them separately.

Do that to an entire codebase and no human brain has the ability to contain it all.

It is nice if you can look at a codebase as if it is a doodle on a gigantic whiteboard, and then take a maker and draw a circle around a relatively small part and go: This bit is entirely self contained; it is used from outside of my little circle, but it's a one-way street. I can define that communication to the outside and then understand just the bits inside it as if it is a muuuuch simpler, smaller application.

A good larger app consists of that concept, hierarchically applied.

You also get considerable benefits when writing tests.

Thus, you get a rule: Avoid writing reference loops in your code if you can. Which your example would break.

## Pointless abstraction

If a class refers to its subclasses, that suggests the feature of 'this class can be subclassed' doesn't "count" - I can't take your code and then write my own subclass, without then updating your parent class (under the assumption that you requiring the subclasses implies that ANY subclass needs to be referred to by the parent). That seems to ruin the point, no?

Note that there is the notion of 'sealed' types, which are types that are meant to be subtyped, but only 'privately' - that is, whilst code in other projects/packages are allowed to see the class, they should not subclass it. Java does not directly support it (but you can 'hack' it: Put the subclasses in the same package, and make the constructor package private, voila) - but sealed types are on the horizon for Java15. In this case, it's potentially acceptable, but you're still breaking the reference loop rule.

Comment: I am so sorry that I made a mistake that I should have written "classes in its subpackages", not "its subclasses".

Comment: Fortunately, the answer more or less stands; if you have reference loops, that's not great. If you don't, eh, I don't think this matters much.